# How to sort a dataset in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, mnist

I would like to sort my dataset by the numerical values in the labels.

Is there a function from pytorch to handle this efficiently?

my dataset `type()` is in this from:

```
 <class 'torchvision.datasets.mnist.MNIST'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generic way to do this efficiently, as the dataset class is only implements a `__getitem__` and `__len__` method, and don't necessarily have any "stored" information about the labels.

In the case of the [MNIST dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/mnist.html#MNIST) class however you can sort the dataset from the label list.

For example when you want to list the indices that have the label 5.

```
mnist = torchvision.datasets.mnist.MNIST("/")
labels = mnist.train_labels
fives = (labels == 5).nonzero()
```

Comment: `mnist.train_labels` appears to have been renamed `mnist.targets` in torchvision version 0.12.0.  I don't know about earlier versions.